# Check URL, delete Query, append URL with another Query, only if other queries do not exist in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change a URL on page load, let's say it's this:

```
https://checkout.mysite.com/232323/checkouts/0e6ednednde8ednedeb9dee7?_ga=1.03574.14822555185.1111142244&locale=en&sid=qwdjuwd6dnewqd8ewdb2
```

First I need to remove `?ga=1.03574.14822555185.1111142244&locale=en&sid=qwdjuwd6dnewqd8ewdb2`

```js
function getPathFromUrl(url) {
    return url.split("?")[0];
}
```

Also I need to check that none of these are present in the URL, and if they are not present, append the URL with the query I have in `window.location.href`

```js
if (document.location.href.indexOf("contact_information") &&         
    ("shipping_method") && 
    ("payment_method") && 
    ("contact_information") != 1) {
    window.location.href('Contact Info', 'Title', '?step=contact_information');
}
```

However This doesn't seem to be working, in fact I can't split the URL for some reason. Can these be used together?

Comment: Your if statement logic is incorrect. To test multiple conditions you need to write the full condition each time. Also note that `href` is a string property, so I'm unsure of the exact outcome you're expecting of the current logic.

Comment: ... and i guess it should be `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: And also you check if `!= 1` but `indexOf` returns `-1` if the substring is not present, so it's totally unclear what you're actually checking..